# How to stop views overlapping in Framelayout?

Tags: android

I have a framelayout and everythinhg inside it is on top of each other. How can I make it like a vertical layout for some elements and overlap only some other views?

How can i choose which views overlap and which don't?

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" >
      <TextView
            android:id="@+id/top"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
            android:paddingBottom="2dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="9sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/undertop"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
            android:paddingBottom="2dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="9sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: FrameLayout isn't necessary best layout for this purpose. Have you considered using RelativeLayout instead?

Comment: @code578841441 Use `android:layout_gravity` to specify where you want the elements in your frame layout to be.